How to add semicircles overlying geom_point in ggplot2
I am trying to generate a dotplot that shows changes in virus infection over time in multiple individuals. More than one virus can be detected, and I want each virus to have its own color in the dotplot. Where it gets complicated is when an individual has more than one virus at the same timepoint. I would like to display this data by showing the 2nd virus as a semicircle on top of the first virus present. I have been playing around with this and it looks like adding a 2nd geom_point layer in ggplot2 with a unicode character for a semicircle (e.g. "\u25D7") is one of the easier ways to do this. However, I'm running into two issues.
First: I can't get the unicode characters to display in any ggplot. I get the hollow square of failure instead.
Second: I need to suppress one of the result categories ("Neg" in "Res2") so that semicircles are only imposed at dots where two viruses are detected simultaneously.
Any advice would be greatly appreciated! I'm running R v 4.4.0 with English_United States.utf8 on Windows 10.
Some example data and code:
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)

AnimalID<-c("A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","C","C","C","C","C")
Week<-c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5)
Res1<-c("HV1","HV1","Neg","HV2","Neg","Neg","HV2","HV1","HV1","HV1","HV1","HV1","HV2","Neg","HV1")
Res2<-c("HV2","Neg","Neg","Neg","Neg","Neg","Neg","HV2","Neg","Neg","Neg","HV2","Neg","Neg","Neg")
AllHV<-c("HV1 and HV2","HV1","Neg","HV2","Neg","Neg","HV2","HV1 and HV2","HV1","HV1","HV1","HV1 and      HV2","HV2","Neg","HV1")
     
db<-data.frame(AnimalID,Week,Res1,Res2,AllHV)

Exgraph<-
ggplot(db,aes(x= Week, y=AnimalID, color=Res1)) + 
geom_point(size=3,shape=16) +
theme_tufte() +
ggtitle("HV Shedding Patterns") +
xlab("Study Week") +
ylab("Animal ID") +
theme(axis.line = element_line(colour = "black")) +
theme(plot.title = element_text(face = "bold",size=18)) +
theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 10)) +
theme(axis.title = element_text(face = "bold",size = 14)) +
theme(legend.title = element_text(size = 14, face = "bold"),legend.text = element_text(size = 11)) +
labs(color='HV')+
geom_point(aes(x= Week, y=AnimalID, color=Res2)) ## this is where I'd be adding the unicode +
scale_color_manual(values=c("green","blue","grey80"))

Exgraph`


A more elaborated option would be to use some custom shapes. The approach below builds on this answer by @AllanCameron (which I already applied here) and this answer by @Baptiste to create the custom shape using grid:
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)
library(purrr)
library(grid)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpmisc)

pal_color <- c(HV1 = "green", HV2 = "blue", Neg = "grey80")

custom_shape <- function(r1 = .1,
                         r2 = r1,
                         scale = 1,
                         angle = 0,
                         shape = "full",
                         gp = gpar()) {
  if (shape == "half") {
    th2 <- seq(0, pi, length = 180)
    th1 <- th2 + pi
    d1 <- r1 * scale * cbind(cos(th1 + angle * pi / 180), sin(th1 + angle * pi / 180))
    d2 <- r2 * scale * cbind(cos(th2 + angle * pi / 180), sin(th2 + angle * pi / 180))

    polygonGrob(
      unit(c(d1[, 1], d2[, 1]), "snpc") + unit(0.5, "npc"),
      unit(c(d1[, 2], d2[, 2]), "snpc") + unit(0.5, "npc"),
      id = rep(1:2, each = length(th1)),
      gp = gp
    )
  } else {
    circleGrob(
      x = unit(0.5, "npc"),
      y = unit(0.5, "npc"),
      r = r1 * scale,
      gp = gp
    )
  }
}

db <- db |>
  mutate(
    is_neg = Res1 == "Neg" | Res2 == "Neg",
    is_full = (Res1 == Res2) | is_neg,
    shape = if_else(is_full, "full", "half"),
    fill = purrr::map2(Res1, Res2, ~ unique(pal_color[c(.x, .y)])),
    grob = purrr::pmap(
      list(fill = fill, shape = shape),
      \(fill, shape) {
        custom_shape(
          shape = shape,
          gp = gpar(fill = fill, col = NA),
          angle = 90,
          scale = 1
        )
      }
    )
  )

ggplot(db, aes(x = Week, y = AnimalID, color = Res1)) +
  # Only used to get a legend
  geom_point(x = NA, y = NA, na.rm = TRUE) +
  #
  geom_grob(aes(x = Week, y = AnimalID, label = grob)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = pal_color) +
  labs(
    title = "HV Shedding Patterns",
    x = "Study Week",
    y = "Animal ID",
    color = "HV"
  )


UPDATE The code below offers a refactored version of custom_shape which now allows for circles of an arbitrary numbers of parts.
pal_color <- c(HV1 = "green", HV2 = "blue", HV3 = "red", Neg = "grey80")

custom_shape <- function(r = .1,
                         scale = 1,
                         angle = 0,
                         n = 1,
                         gp = gpar()) {
  make_polygon_data <- function(n = 1, r = .1, scale = 1) {
    th_base <- seq(0, 2 * pi / n, length = 180)
    th <- lapply(seq_len(n), \(i) th_base + (i - 1) * 2 * pi / n)

    lapply(th, \(th) {
      r * scale * cbind(
        c(0, cos(th + angle * pi / 180), 0),
        c(0, sin(th + angle * pi / 180), 0)
      )
    })
  }

  d <- make_polygon_data(n, r = r, scale = scale)

  x <- Reduce(\(xx, x) c(xx, x[, 1]), d, NULL)
  y <- Reduce(\(yy, y) c(yy, y[, 2]), d, NULL)

  polygonGrob(
    unit(x, "snpc") + unit(0.5, "npc"),
    unit(y, "snpc") + unit(0.5, "npc"),
    id = rep(seq_len(n), each = 182),
    gp = gp
  )
}

tibble(
  x = seq(5),
  n = seq(5),
  fill = purrr::map(seq(5), \(n) scales::hue_pal()(n))
) |>
  mutate(
    grob = map2(
      fill, n,
      \(fill, n) {
        custom_shape(
          n = n,
          gp = gpar(fill = fill, col = NA),
          scale = 4
        )
      }
    )
  ) |>
  ggplot() +
  geom_grob(aes(x = factor(x), y = factor(x), label = grob))


And now applied to your real data where I added a third results column Res3:
set.seed(123)

db$Res3 <- sample(c("HV1", "HV2", "HV3", "Neg"), nrow(db), replace = TRUE)

db <- db |>
  mutate(
    is_neg = rowSums(across(c(Res1, Res2, Res3), ~ .x == "Neg")) > 0,
    n = purrr::pmap_int(list(Res1, Res2, Res3), \(x, y, z) n_distinct(c(x, y, z))),
    n = if_else(is_neg, 1, n),
    fill = purrr::pmap(list(Res1, Res2, Res3), \(x, y, z) unique(pal_color[c(x, y, z)])),
    grob = map2(
      fill, n,
      \(fill, n) {
        custom_shape(
          n = n,
          gp = gpar(fill = fill, col = NA),
          angle = 90,
          scale = 1
        )
      }
    )
  )

ggplot(db, aes(x = Week, y = AnimalID)) +
  # Only used to get a legend
  geom_point(
    data = data.frame(color = names(pal_color)),
    aes(color = color),
    x = NA, y = NA, na.rm = TRUE
  ) +
  #
  geom_grob(aes(x = Week, y = AnimalID, label = grob)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = pal_color) +
  labs(
    title = "HV Shedding Patterns",
    x = "Study Week",
    y = "Animal ID",
    color = "HV"
  )



Thanks, this worked! In my real dataset there is another virus that I'd like to show as a third overlaid semicircle in the appropriate spots (bottom half of a circle, ideally). I am completely new to polygonGrob and circleGrob, and am finding the code a little dense. Would it be better to manipulate "angle" in custom_shape or within the mutate section of code to rotate a new semicircle character? Within the mutate code segment, I should just be able to replace "Res1" with "Res2" and "Res2" with "Res3" (assuming Res3 is another variable similar to Res1 and Res2) to get this to work, right?

Whoops, forgot to @stefan. I've been playing around with trying to add the third layer of custom_shapes without success.

See my update. I refactored the function to allow for circles with an arbitrary number of parts. Perhaps this fits your needs.

This renders a semicircle:
geom_text(aes(x = Week, y = AnimalID, label = "\u25D1"))


geom_point also supports text glyphs, so I expect if that didn't work, geom_text will not work either (for me they both show the hollow square).

I'm running this in Rstudio with Tools > Global Options > General > Graphics Graphics Device Backend: AGG. If I use the quartz device, I get empty rectangles. In Positron, I have to use ggsave  with the png device
ggsave("semicircle.png", device = "png")

Thanks for this info too @MichielDuvekot! After adjusting the graphics settings I'm finally actually able to see the unicode shapes (and save the figures!). I've gone through lots of other unicode answers to try to make this work and this is the only thing that has actually done the job. This just leaves the second part of my question: I need to suppress one of the result categories ("Neg" in "Res2") so that semicircles are only imposed at dots where two viruses are detected simultaneously. Do you know of a streamlined way to do this portion?
